# Symmetric group $S_4$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

Let $G$ be the Symmetric group $S_4.$ Give a representative of each conjugacy class of $G.$ Then calculate the size of each conjugacy class.

I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Do you know how to decompose a permutation into a product of disjoint cycles? If yes, see http://people.virginia.edu/~mve2x/3354_Fall2010/lecture21.pdf (Theorem 21.1.). And also see Example on page 3.

Comment: Step 1. Prove that two elements of $S_n$ are conjugate in $S_n$ if and only if they have the same cycle structure.